# Crawl recursively and write to file in asynchronous manner

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, fs

I'm completely new to asynchronous code, so I'm in way over my head right now.

What I'm doing is recursively crawling an archive asynchronously in order to detect file paths in the given archive. What I'm trying to do is then write all of the file paths as they're detected to a single file. When I execute the code, however, it doesn't write them to the file properly. I'm assuming this is due to multiple writes coinciding with one another.

## data.json before

```
{
  "K": {
    "files": []
  }
}
```

## data.json after

```
{
  "K": {
    "files": [
      {
        "name": "Testing.txt",
        "bytes": 1648,
        "path": "K:\\Texts\\Testing.txt"
      }
    ]
  }
}      }
    ]
  }
}
}.txt"
      }
    ]
  }
}    }
    ]
  }
}
```

I could obviously write the code synchronously, but I'd prefer to do all of this asynchronously for the sake of efficiency. Nonetheless, I'm really not sure the best way to go about this. I know one way to do this would be to wait until the last file is crawled and pushed (and then write the new property to file), but I have no idea how to efficiently detect that in an asynchronous environment? I could check every so often, yet this is a dumb approach in my opinion.

Below is my asynchronous code that's causing issues.

```
// Scan directories looking for target file types.
async function scanDirs(){
  const
    config = await fsp.readFile('./config.json', 'utf8'),
    archives = JSON.parse(config).archives,
    { join } = require('path'),
    traverse = async (path) => {
      try {
        const stats = await fsp.stat(path)
        if (stats.isDirectory()){
          const childPaths = await fsp.readdir(path)
          for (const childPath of childPaths){
            const
              fullPath = join(path, childPath)
            traverse(fullPath)
          }
        } else if (stats.isFile()) {
          const
            fileTypes = config.fileTypes,
            fileExt = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.')+1)
          if (fileTypes.includes(fileExt)){
            const
              data = await fsp.readFile('./data.json', 'utf8'),
              json = JSON.parse(data),
              drive = path.substring(0,1),
              files = json[drive].files,
              stat = await fsp.stat(path),
              newFile = {
                "path": path,
                "name": path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('\\')+1),
                "bytes": stat.size
              }
            files.push(newFile)
            fsp.writeFile('./data.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 2))
          }
        }
      }
      catch (error){
        console.error(error)
      }
    }

  for (const path of archives){
    traverse(path)
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Build the data structure recursively in your function, return it as (a promise for) an object. Then wait for that, serialise it, and write it to the file only once.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't care about the structure"? Surely the garbled output is not fine?

Comment: @Bergi all im recording is the paths of files which im sticking into an array

Comment: @Bergi im so confused about how to return `traverse` as a promise. im calling `traverse` an indefinite number of times from a `for` loop, which in turn calls itself an indefinite number of times. im brand new to promises and asynchronous code, so explain it to me like im 5 years old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know one way to do this would be to wait until the last file is crawled before writing, but I have no idea how to efficiently detect that in an asynchronous environment?

You would use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for multiple promises:

```
const { join } = require('path');
async function searchFiles(path, fileTypes) {
  try {
    const stats = await fsp.stat(path)
    if (stats.isDirectory()){
      const childPaths = await fsp.readdir(path)
      const promises = childPaths.map(childPath =>
        searchFiles(join(path, childPath), fileTypes)
      );
      const results = await Promise.all(promises);
      return [].concat(...results);
    } else if (stats.isFile()) {
      const fileExt = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.')+1)
      if (fileTypes.includes(fileExt)) {
        return [{
          "path": path,
          "name": path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('\\')+1),
          "bytes": stats.size
        }];
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // ignore. Log?
  }
  return [];
}
async function readJson(path) {
  return JSON.parse(await fsp.readFile(path, 'utf8'));
}

// Scan directories looking for target file types.
async function scanDirs() {
  try {
    const [config, data] = await Promise.all([readJson('./config.json'), readJson('./data.json')]);
    const results = await Promise.all(config.archives.map(path => searchFiles(path, config.fileTypes)));
    for (const newFile of [].concat(...results)) {
      const drive = newFile.path.substring(0,1);
      data[drive].files.push(newFile);
    }
    fsp.writeFile('./data.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  } catch (error){
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

Btw you might want to consider using `basename` and `extname` from the [`path` module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) instead of string manipulation, but given this is a windows-only program (working with drive letters) it probably doesn't matter a lot.

Comment: im gonna play around with this right now so that i can understand whats happening. appreciate your help

Comment: so basically any asynchronous function is essentially a promise, correct?

Comment: also, when i call `readJson('path')` from a different function, is `readJson` in the new context an awaited promise? for instance, `async someOtherFunction(){ const c = readJson('./config.json'), d = c.archives }`, `d` will always await `c` in this context or no matter the context?

Comment: @PrimitiveNom Every `async`hronous function *returns* a promise, yes.

Comment: @PrimitiveNom The context won't wait for until you explicitly `await` the promise. No, the `d` in your example won't wait for `c`, it doesn't know or care what `readJson` does. The "waiting context" is only the current `async function`, whose execution is suspended (like a generator) until the currently awaited promise settled. No other code in other functions is affected by this.

Comment: so `scanDirs` is throwing an error, saying `undefined is not a function`, which im assuming means i have to explicitly `await` both `Promise.all...`?

Comment: Ooops… yes I meant to do that

Comment: so yeah i did `await` them and it fixed that error, but now `scanDirs` is throwing the `EPERM: operation not permitted, stat` error which seems to be derailing the whole function, so that it never ends up writing anything to file. now u see why i wanted to sort the permission thing out out? :p anyways, i wrapped the statements of `searchFiles` in a `try` block, but its returning `undefined` for a number of items that throw that permission error. any idea how to filter out the errors/the `undefined`?

Comment: nm think i figured it out. i can just `return []` in the `catch` block. do u foresee any issues with doing this? for some reason its still not writing to file tho :/ i think ive figured it out

Comment: Oh, right, you were originally catching errors in the `traverse` function, not in the `scanDirs` one. I assumed you wouldn't want to write anything in case there were errors, but if you just want to ignore paths where you got an error then yes you'd need to change that and have it return an empty array for those.

Comment: yeah i still want to write. the only reason im getting those errors is because of system permission. what i can do is disregard that one particular error and handle other errors differently

Comment: its still not writing to file. so weird. i can log `newFile` in the `for` loop, and it spits out all the diff objects, but for some reason i cant access the `path` property via `newFile.path` or `newFile[path]`, says its not defined. yet for some reason i can access an individual objects `path` property with `newFile[i].path`

Comment: the max number of items an array can hold is 100??

Comment: any idea why its chopping `results` up into two separate arrays of 100 and 33 items? i had to change the code to `results.forEach((newFile, i) => { const drive = newFile[i].path.substring(0,1); data[drive].files.push(newFile)})` to get it actually working, but even if i print `newFile[i]` from inside the loop, it only prints the very first item of the first array and nothing else. so confusing

Comment: Oops, I forgot to flatten the `results` in `scanDirs`, it's an array of arrays (one for each `archives` path).

Comment: ohhh no wonder. strange too it was just a single nested array i.e. `[[all the objects were here]]`

Comment: turned out in the end i didnt need to flatten `results` so that i could wipe the `files` array when scanning the archives. thanks again buddy <3